# format json object for rendering morris donut

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5, morris.js

i am trying to render morris donut chart however my data format is incorrect, can anyone help with converting to the correct format?

DATA:

```
"[{"Agent Channel":null,"TY":2143315},{"Agent Channel":"Agent","TY":189927},{"Agent Channel":"Internet Sale","TY":12466},{"Agent Channel":"Walk In","TY":11969}]"
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Agent Channel
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="sales-agent-channel" style="height: 250px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    function createChart(data) {
        var mychart = new Morris.Donut({
            element: 'sales-agent-channel',
            data: data
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("AgentChannel", "Sales")',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            debugger;
            createChart(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: don't need `JSON.parse` I guess, `data` may already be an object

Comment: seems you are correct however my object is not in the correct format to render morris donut, it needs to be {label:"xxxx", value: xxxx} how do i convert it to the format for morris donut?

Comment: How do you retrieve the `JSON` object?